# Lumix G7 - exposure preview

Tags: camera-settings, panasonic-lumix

I have a Lumix G7 and I use it in manual mode. The live view image always uses auto brightness no matter if my settings are to under- or overexpose. Is there no option to see a brightness preview in live view?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by set in menu Monitor / Display -> Constant Preview to On.

This will set it for viewfinder and for rear screen. The disadvantage is when you use slow shutter speed you will have challenge to compose the image.
If you want you can assign this switch to some button to simplify on/off switch